# Python type hinting decorator with specific arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, type-hinting, false-positive

Consider a wrapper that gets a class instance `self` and makes use of it before calling the decorated function:

```
def some_decorator(func: Callable[[Foo], None]):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrap(self: Foo) -> None:
        # Logic requiring the use of self
        func(self)
    return wrap

class Foo:
    @some_decorator
    def bar(self) -> None:
        return None
```

Calling `bar` as `Foo().bar()` should be equivalent to `Foo.bar(Foo())`, but PyCharm's type checker complains about the former: `Parameter 'self' unfilled`. Upon removing the decorator from the function, the type checker works as expected and the two methods are considered equivalent.

How can I make the type checker realize that the two are equivalent, even with the decorator, and that there is no problem?

Note that I don't consider using `def wrap(*args)` and `func(*args)` as a solution as it completely avoids type checking.

Comment: Can you please specify what version of PyCharm you are running?

Comment: @user144153 I'm running the most recent stable version of it: PyCharm 2021.1.1

Comment: Is the problem that you didn't annotate `self` in the definition of `Foo.bar`? As far as the static type checker is concerned, the *function* `bar` could take any argument. When you call `Foo().bar()`, then `self` is bound to an instance of `Foo`, but that's not (statically speaking) the only possibility.

Comment: @chepner Because `bar` is defined within a class, the first parameter, `self`,  is automatically inferred as type `Foo`. Annotating it makes no difference. `self` is only annotated in `wrap` because that doesn't get its type for free. While naming it `self` can be considered questionable, it doesn't change the outcome either way.

Comment: I'm wondering, does mypy also has this flaw?

Comment: @RoyCohen No, but it also does not find an issue with `Foo().bar(5, 34)` while it should complain about the two extra arguments.